# <connectionString> section is not being encrypted in app.config

Tags: .net, vb.net, encryption

Following the [MS guide](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms254494%28v=vs.90%29.aspx?cs-save-lang=1&cs-lang=vb#code-snippet-9), I am trying to encrypt entire `<connectionString>` section in app.config file. While the program is running, I can open `bin/Debug/MyApp.vshost.exe.config` and see that `<connectionString>` is encrypted. However, if I let the program run, finish up and exit normally, nothing get saved in the file, as if it flushes all the settings.

```
  Dim config As Configuration =  
    ConfigurationManager.OpenExeConfiguration(ConfigurationUserLevel.None)
    Dim section As ConnectionStringsSection =  
    DirectCast(config.GetSection("connectionStrings"), ConnectionStringsSection)
    If section.SectionInformation.IsProtected Then
        'Remove encryption 
        section.SectionInformation.UnprotectSection()
    Else
        'Encrypt  
         section.SectionInformation.ProtectSection("DataProtectionConfigurationProvider")
    End If
        section.SectionInformation.ForceSave = True
        config.Save(ConfigurationSaveMode.Full)
    Dim sectionXmlas As String = 'result of encryption 
                    section.SectionInformation.GetRawXml()
```

Comment: You have to call config.refreshsection to make this work

Answer (score 0):

To make this work Programmatically, you would have to call

```
config.refreshsection
```

The call to Save will adjust the physical file but it will be cached in memory until the above call is made.

Comment: Just tried, there is no  `.refreshsection` command/function in `Configuration` class https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.configuration.configuration%28v=vs.110%29.aspx

Comment: `RefreshSection` is a shared function in the  `ConfigurationManager` class. Call `ConfigurationManager.RefreshSection(sectionName)` with the section name that you want to refresh.

Comment: @theduck `ConfigurationManager.RefreshSection("connectionStrings")` doesn't do anything either

Comment: I think `GetRawXML()` decrypts protected sections before returning the data - so you will always get unencrypted data back from the call. Can you see the change made in the underlying file? `section.SectionInformation.IsProtected` should return true after the call to `ProtectSection()`.

Comment: @theduck I placed break point after `config.Save(ConfigurationSaveMode.Full)` and opened the `bin/debug/MyApplication.vshost.exe.Config` file (Naively, I was expecting it to see changes in app.config in Visual Studio). And indeed, `<connectionStrings>` is encrypted. However, if I let the program run, and then exit normally, re-open config file, it reverts back to unencrypted text. Which is rather odd.

Comment: You might see some strange behaviour in the vshost version of that file. What happens if you run the program directly rather than through Visual Studio? You should see the encryption sticks around.

Comment: @theduck Indeed, it works if I run my program directly, it saves the changes. This behavior is very odd, now you don't know which file to modify, in order to save the settings.